# Defining specific Exponentiation in PA

Tags: first-order-logic, peano-axioms

Given the dictionary {0,1,+,*,<} can I write a simple formula with only x occurs free, that states "x is an exponent of 6"?

When I say simple, I mean, without using complicated techniques like Betta function.
Thanks

Comment: Not recursive formula either, I assume?

Comment: How can you write it in the language?